# How to add values from radio options into cart list

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

so i'm trying to create a cart system where for every time i select a radio button / checkbox the relative values get mapped into the cart list so i can display the specific selcted items into a different widget

code below is used to basically manage the cart :

```
final cartProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider<CartNotifier>((ref) => CartNotifier());

class CartNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Menu> _cart = []; //empty list to add items into for cart

  List<Menu> get cart => _cart;

  void addProduct(Menu menu) {
    _cart.add(menu);
    notifyListeners();
  } //add products into cart

  void removeProduct(e) {
    _cart.remove(e);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

then below these are checkbox / radio options values im trying to get listed into the cart based of selction :

```
 RadioListTile(
                              value: 2,
                              groupValue: _value,
                              onChanged: ((value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _value = value as int;
                                  model.addProduct(e);
                                });
                              }),
                              title: Text(
                                e.mealSize_2,
                              ),
                            ),
                            RadioListTile(
                              value: 3,
                              groupValue: _value,
                              onChanged: ((value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _value = value as int;
                                  model.addProduct(e);
                                });
                              }),
                              title: Text(
                                e.mealSize_3,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const Divider(thickness: 8),
                            CheckboxListTile(
                                controlAffinity:
                                    ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                title: Text(e.mealChoice_1),
                                value: check1,
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    check1 = val!;
                                    if (check1 == true) {
                                      model.addProduct(e);
                                    }
                                  });
                                }),
                            CheckboxListTile(
                                controlAffinity:
                                    ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                title: Text(e.mealChoice_2),
                                value: check2,
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    check2 = val;
                                    model.addProduct(e);
                                  });
                                }),
```

below is where i'm trying to map values from the cart list:

```
Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 0, 24, 24),
                              child: MaterialButton(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                color: Colors.black,
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  model.addProduct(e);

                                  showModalBottomSheet(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (context) {
                                        return Column(
                                          children: [
                                            ...model.cart.map(
                                              (item) => Column(children: [
                                                Text(item.mealName),
                                              ]),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      });
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                  "Add to cart",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color:
                                          Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 245, 245)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: Please ask a question related to the info you provided

Comment: I want to know how can i add values from a radio button into an empty cart list ?